# Version is being changed when editing document properties

Tags: document, metadata, properties

Is it possible to edit "Properties" of a document?

Each time I edit "properties" of any document, version is being changed. Is it possible to edit and it remain in same version?

Answer (score 2):

That is what happens when you select the overwrite option when check-in the document. Then it will not update the version number.

Answer (score 0):

To disable versioning in library go to :

Library settings > Versioning settings > Choose No Versioning option

Comment: This disables **ALL** versioning, not just when editing properties as the original question asked

Comment: Choosing no version opetion it creats major version 1.0 2.0 3.0   and   it does not show overwrite option when i edit properties. It comes when you upload new version of document.